# Haskell - need to define Vector2 instance for typeclass

Tags: haskell

```
newtype Vector2 a = Vector2 (a,a)
     deriving (Show,Eq)

class VectorSpace v where
     vZero :: (Num a) => v a
     vSum :: (Num a) => v a -> v a -> v a
     vScalarProd :: (Num a) => a -> v a -> v a
     vMagnitude :: (Floating a) => v a -> a
```

Need to define for Vector2 to be instances of the type class VectorSpace.

Comment: Great vector space! What is your question?

Comment: oh I need to create an instance statement to define for Vector2...but I am new to Haskell...and clue ?

Comment: I would argue that this is not [the class of vector spaces](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.15/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html#t:VectorSpace). Vector spaces aren't supposed to be parameterised over the scalar type. Your class is actually more about representable functors, which is what the [linear library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear) is based on. I recommend you look into the source both of these libraries, to answer the question.

Comment: @Yorkman: but being new to something is not an excuse for lack of effort. What did you try? What is not working?

Comment: ...or if you really don't have any clue at all how to start, you should probably first read an introduction to Haskell in general. IMO [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) is still the best point of entry, though many people prefer [Haskell from First Principles](http://haskellbook.com/) nowadays.

Comment: So here is what I tried so far :                                                               
instance VectorSpace (a,a) => VectorSpace Vector2 a 
  vecZero = (0.0,0.0)   
  vecSum (x,y) (x',y') = (x+x',y+y')

Comment: oh don't know, that's what the question i was being asked....

Comment: Please don't add code in the comments; put your attempt in the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

> So here is what I tried so far:
>
> ```
> instance VectorSpace (a,a) => VectorSpace Vector2 a
>   vecZero = (0.0,0.0)
>   vecSum (x,y) (x',y') = (x+x',y+y')
> ```

The first problem here is syntax. You need a `where` at the end of the first line, and if `Vector2 a` is supposed to be the instance head then it needs to go in parentheses:

```
instance VectorSpace (a,a) => VectorSpace (Vector2 a) where
```

That, however, doesn't match the kinds of your declared class.

```
class VectorSpace (v :: * -> *) where
    vZero :: (Num a) => v a
    ...
```

i.e., the class already has the assumption built in that `v` will be applied to some `a` parameter<sup>†</sup>. Thus the instance head should *not* contain that parameter, it should just look like

```
instance (...?) => VectorSpace Vector2 where
```

In fact it turns out you don't need any constraints at all here.

```
instance VectorSpace Vector2 where
```

Now as for the methods,

> ```
>   vecSum (x,y) (x',y') = (x+x',y+y')
> ```

that would be a perfectly sensible implementation if your type were the tuple type. However your type is actually a `newtype` wrapped tuple, and `newtypes` always need explicit constructors. Like

```
  vecSum (Vector2 (x,y)) (Vector2 (x',y')) = Vector2 (x+x',y+y')
```

This is a bit silly really: you have both a named constructor and a tuple constructor, nested. It's also pretty inefficient since tuples incur extra indirection (laziness, cache). The type should better be defined as

```
data Vector2 a = Vector2 !a !a
```

where, because the fields are strict, GHC can unbox the numbers. In that case, the definition would be

```
  vecSum (Vector2 x y) (Vector2 x' y') = Vector2 (x+x') (y+y')
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Mind, as I've already commented it is IMO **not** good for a vector space class to parameterise `v a` at all. In the [`vector-space` library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.15/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html#t:VectorSpace), the instances aren't required to be parameterised; one of the advantages is that you can directly give an instance for ordinary tuples without needing any newtype wrapping.</sub>

Comment: thanks it works  for the vecSum, but I got an error for vecZero = (0.0,0.0) as it is a zero vector constant....do you know why?

Comment: I just updated my last line...do you have any idea to fix vecZero ?

Comment: It's the same issue as I explained for `vecSum`.

Comment: I tried with this but still got error   vecZero (Vector2 (0.0,0.0))