# How do I resolve this error in Haskell coding with vector

Tags: haskell

```
newtype Vector2 a = Vector2 (a,a)
   deriving (Show,Eq)

instance VectorSpace Vector2 where 
  vecMagnitude (Vector2 (a,b)) = (a**2 + b**2)**(1/2)

vecF :: (Floating a, VectorSpace v) => v a -> [v a] -> [a]
vecF Vector2 (a,b) ys = [ vecMagnitude ( Vector2 (a+(-1)*a'),(b+(-1)*b') ) |(a',b') <- ys ]
```

So the above coding I have errors with is the vecF function, see the following error msg :

```
Couldn't match type ‘v’ with ‘(,) a0’
  ‘v’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      vecF :: forall a (v :: * -> *).
              (Floating a, VectorSpace v) =>
              v a -> [v a] -> [a]
    at Assign_2_EC_test.hs:74:1-58
  Expected type: v a
    Actual type: (a0, a)

In the pattern: (a, b)
  In an equation for ‘vecF’:
      vecF (a, b) ys
        = [vecMagnitude ((a + (- 1) * a'), (b + (- 1) * b')) |
             (a', b') <- ys]
Relevant bindings include
    vecF :: v a -> [v a] -> [a]
```

Any idea what was the error

Comment: Your example is missing imports, could you add those?

Comment: @MichaelLitchard: these are defined in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52778291/haskell-need-to-define-vector2-instance-for-typeclass but you are correct that it is better to include these to make the question more "canned".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically four problems here: two can be solved easilyk, the others will require to change the signature, or implementing extra functions:

1. you forgot to write brackets in the head of the function:

   ```
   vecF (Vector2 (a,b)) ys = ...
   ```
2. the brackets in the "yield" part of the list comprehension do not have brackets to make a tuple:

   ```
   [ vecMagnitude (Vector2 (a+(-1)*a', b+(-1)*b')) | ... ]
   ```
3. in your signature you allow the first parameter to be any `v a` with `v` a `VectorSpace` type, and `a` a `Floating` type, so you can not just add a constructor like:

   ```
   vecF (Vector2 (a, b)) = ...
   ```
4. (can not be solved in a straightforward way) since `ys` is a list of `v a`s, you can not just enumerate from `ys` as:

   ```
   [ ... | (a', b') <- ys ]
   ```

The last two problems can not be solved easily, we can *specialize* the signature such that it works, like:

```
vecF :: Floating a => Vector2 a -> [(a, a)] -> [a]
vecF (Vector2 (a,b)) ys = [ vecMagnitude ( Vector2 (a-a',b-b')) |(a',b') <- ys ]
```

but then we of course loose the flexibitily to use other `VectorSpace`s, another option is for example to move `vecF` to the `class` definition and implement it in the `instance` clause. Finally another option might be to make extra functions such that you do not need pattern matching to calculate the `vecMaginute`, you can for example implement a function:

```
class VectorSpace v where
    -- ...
    vecDiff :: Num a => v a -> v a -> v a
```

and then you can implement this as:

```
vecF :: (Floating a, VectorSpace v) => v a -> [v a] -> [a]
vecF v0 vs = [ vecMagnitude (vecDiff v0 v1) | v1 <- vs ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and I think I have made the changes you advise.  My question is when I tested it, I got error    vecF (1,2) [(0,0),(1,1),(2,2)]...do you know what's wrong?

Comment: @Yorkman: well the parameters here are a `Vector2` and a list of 2-tuples, you first parameters is a 2-tuple, so it should be `vecF (Vector2 (1,2)) [(0,0), (1,1), (2,2)]`. But I thin the last approach is probably the best: implementing a function that can calculate the difference between two `VectorSpace` type objects.

Comment: hi...there is no compile error however, when I try to test with your vecDiff                   
          vecF (Vector2 (1,2)) [(0,0), (1,1), (2,2)]                                       
I go the following error                                                                                 
    Couldn't match type ‘(,) Integer’ with ‘Vector2’
      Expected type: Vector2 a
        Actual type: (Integer, a)
    In the expression: (0, 0)
      In the second argument of ‘vecF’, namely ‘[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)]’
      In the expression: vecF (Vector2 (1, 2)) [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)]

Comment: @Yorkman: yes, in case you make a function with `vecDif`, you add the flexibility that the vectorspace of the first parameter is the same as the elements in the list, but not two different one, so `vecF (Vector2 (1,2)) [Vector2 (0,0)]`.

Comment: @Yorkman please don't continually get back at questions you asked, when the problem has shifted. First make sure you've really tried everything you could to solve it yourself, and that it is worthwhile going to SO, then ask a new, self-contained question about the new problem.