# Haskell: Non type-variable argument in the constraint?

Tags: haskell, types, error-handling, compiler-errors

This is the code, it is a bit non-straightforward I apologize. Basically the function vecF is supposed to have two results v1,v2 if entering two inputs v0 and vs, but for some reason I end up getting error messages.

```
newtype Vector2 a = Vector2 (a,a)
  deriving (Show,Eq)
newtype Vector3 a = Vector3 (a,a,a)
  deriving (Show,Eq)
newtype Vector4 a = Vector4 (a,a,a,a)
  deriving (Show,Eq)

class VectorSpace v where
  vecZero       :: (Num a) => v a
  vecSum        :: (Num a) => v a -> v a -> v a
  vecScalarProd :: (Num a) => a -> v a -> v a
  vecMagnitude  :: (Floating a) => v a -> a
  vecInnerProd  :: (Num a) => v a -> v a-> a

instance VectorSpace Vector2 where
  vecZero = Vector2 (0,0)
  vecSum (Vector2 (q,w)) (Vector2 (a,s)) = Vector2 (q+a,w+s)
  vecScalarProd x (Vector2 (q,w)) = Vector2 (q*x,w*x)
  vecMagnitude (Vector2 (q,w)) = sqrt(q*q+w*w)
  vecInnerProd (Vector2 (q,w)) (Vector2 (a,s)) = q*a+w*s

instance VectorSpace Vector3 where
  vecZero = Vector3 (0,0,0)
  vecSum (Vector3 (q,w,e)) (Vector3 (a,s,d)) = Vector3 (q+a,w+s,e+d)
  vecScalarProd x (Vector3 (q,w,e)) = Vector3 (q*x,w*x,e*x)
  vecMagnitude (Vector3 (q,w,e)) = sqrt(q*q+w*w+e*e)
  vecInnerProd (Vector3 (q,w,e)) (Vector3 (a,s,d)) = q*a+w*s+e*d

instance VectorSpace Vector4 where
  vecZero = Vector4 (0,0,0,0)
  vecSum (Vector4 (q,w,e,r)) (Vector4 (a,s,d,f)) = Vector4 
(q+a,w+s,e+d,r+f)
  vecScalarProd x (Vector4 (q,w,e,r)) = Vector4 (q*x,w*x,e*x,r*x)
  vecMagnitude (Vector4 (q,w,e,r)) = sqrt(q*q+w*w+e*e+r*r)
  vecInnerProd (Vector4 (q,w,e,r))(Vector4 (a,s,d,f)) =
    q*a+w*s+e*d+r*f

vecF :: (Floating a, Ord a, VectorSpace v) => v a -> [v a] -> (v a, v a)
vecF v0 vs = (v1,v2) where
            v0Neg     = vecScalarProd (-1) v0
            v1MinMag  = minimumBy (comparing snd)(zip [0..]  
[vecMagnitude (vecSum v0Neg v) | v <- vs])
            v1Index   = fst v1MinMag
            v1Min     = [vecSum v0Neg v | v <- vs] !! v1Index
            v1        = vecSum v0 v1Min

            v2MaxMag  = maximumBy (comparing snd)(zip [0..]  
[vecMagnitude (vecSum v0Neg v) | v <- vs])
            v2Index   = fst v2MaxMag
            v2Max     = [vecSum v0Neg v | v <- vs] !! v2Index
            v2        = vecSum v0 v2Max
```

Below is errors I got when i enter:

```
 vecF (1,2,3,3) [(2,1,2,2),(13,3,2,1)]
```

.

```
 •Non type-variable argument
    in the constraint: VectorSpace ((,,,) t2 t1 t)
  (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
  •When checking the inferred type
    it :: forall a t t1 t2.
          (Num t, Num t1, Num t2, VectorSpace ((,,,) t2 t1 t), Ord a,
           Floating a) =>
          ((t2, t1, t, a), (t2, t1, t, a))
```

I have tried using FlexibleContexts like this,

```
:set -XFlexibleContexts
```

and then I get this new error message

```
 • When checking the inferred type
    it :: forall a t t1 t2.
          (Num t, Num t1, Num t2, VectorSpace ((,,,) t2 t1 t), Ord a,
           Floating a) =>
          ((t2, t1, t, a), (t2, t1, t, a))
• No instance for (VectorSpace ((,,,) t2 t1 t0))
    arising from a use of ‘it’
• In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Note the difference between tuples and your various Vector types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `Vector4` constructor, viz.

```
vecF (Vector4 (1,2,3,3)) [ Vector4 (2,1,2,2), Vector4 (13,3,2,1)]
```

Basically, the error message is telling you exactly what you need to know - namely, that `(1,2,3,3)` has no `VectorSpace` instance. In this case that is because you are calling it on something which is not a vector on its underlying type.

The reason it says there's no instance for `VectorSpace ((,,,) t2 t1 t)` is that it's trying to match the type of `(1, 2, 3, 4)` with `v a` over some `a` - and here it tried to use `Num t, Num t1, Num t2 => (t, t1, t2,)` as the higher-kinded bit.

Comment: I would ([again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52778686/745903)) remark that the lack of a `VectorSpace` instance for `(1,2,3,3)` is because the class is misdesigned. It doesn't really make sense for a vector space to be parameterised over the scalar type. [The preferred vector space class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.15/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html) has the scalar as an associated type family instead. @killderich111 could you say where this comes from? Is it from some kind of tutorial or course?